# The last statement included within a function must be a return statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a function that calculates differently based on the condition.
this is the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION Calc_Price (@Country VARCHAR(100) , @Price REAL , @Tax1 REAL , @Tax2 REAL)
RETURNS REAL AS
    BEGIN
        IF @Country IN ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 15 Country FROM dbo.SUPPLIERS )
        BEGIN
            RETURN @Price + (@Price * @Tax1)
        END                                     
        ELSE 
            RETURN @Price + (@Price * @Tax2)    
    END
```

The Error that I get is

> "The last statement included within a function must be a return statement"

Comment: Exactly as the error says - your return statement is inside your if statement. So instead, assign the return value to a variable the if statement, and then then return it as the last statement.

Comment: Remove the else. Look at the duplicate I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
CREATE FUNCTION Calc_Price (@Country VARCHAR(100) , @Price REAL , @Tax1 REAL , @Tax2 REAL)
RETURNS REAL AS
    BEGIN
        IF @Country IN ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 15 Country FROM dbo.SUPPLIERS )
        BEGIN
            RETURN @Price + (@Price * @Tax1)
        END                                     
            RETURN @Price + (@Price * @Tax2)    
    END
```

This is because using sql server you need to make sure your functions end with a return statement. The Else after the return is the line causing the error since when the function is being compiled it sees the lines `END ELSE` which cause it to bug out.

Comment: Why provide an answer in addition to a perfectly good duplicate? The intention of duplicates is to avoid having the same answer in multiple places :)

Comment: Oh boy, So its a syntax Problem thank god.
Your Solution Fixed it for me, Thank you!

Comment: If it closes it closes. But it took less than 2 seconds of my time and can help the OP so I decided to post an answer and why in this case it errored out. Now he understands the issue and how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Why not to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352194/what-to-do-with-answer-on-duplicate-question